# Trying to change text in a textbox on clicking away with blur

Tags: javascript, blur, dom-events

I'm sorry if this is too simple of a question. I am trying to change all instances of `&` to `and` using the event-handler `blur`.  I am seeming to get no changes on blur even if my function is simply

`id.value = "Random test string";`

so I am assuming this is a problem with the event handler itself.  Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

I have the code for changing `&` commented out because I was checking to see if the function tied to the blur eventhandler was triggering at all, which it was not.  This code also has an HTML file with a text box with an ID of `textid`

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //var for saving the string
    var textvar;
    //var for the texta area
    var id = document.getElementById("textid");
    id.addEventListener("blur", function() {

        //textvar = id.value;
        //textvar = textvar.replace("&", " and ");
        //id.value = textvar;

        textvar = "Correct!!";
        id.value = textvar;

    }, false);
 </script>
```

Comment: It's working fine. You click on the input tag and then click outside.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider this other approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function change(element) {
    let textvar = element.value;
    if (textvar.indexOf('&') !== -1) {
      textvar = textvar.replace("&", " and ");
    }
    element.value = textvar;
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" onblur="change(this)" />
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this could help.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine and as expected:

```
<input type="text" id="textid" />
```

**JS Code**

```
//var for saving the string
var textvar;
//var for the texta area
var id = document.getElementById("textid");

id.addEventListener("blur", function() {
    textvar = id.value;
    textvar = textvar.replace(/\&/g, " and ");
    id.value = textvar;
}, false);
```

You can find the working [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvNwEw) here